# History search (ctrl+r) overflowing terminal with "casual" output

Tags: bash, history

When I try to search a previously used command on bash with CTRL+R the terminal is overflowed with what appears to be some "casual" output, instead of the result of the search. I attach a screenshot of the terminal. I get the same kind of output when using the "history" command. Did anyone encounter this strange behavior before? I am using Ubuntu 18.04.3, if it's any help. Thank you!

[Terminal output after searching the history (ctrl+r)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f65Sx.jpg)

Comment: I think you run a command like that before; it doesn't seem casual

Comment: edit .bash_history and remove that command from there

Comment: I went through the .bash_history file and didn't find any command like that. However I moved the file (.bash_history) in another folder and restarted the pc, it seems fine now. Thanks you both!